# SVG + GSAP mask animation issue with Firefox

Tags: animation, firefox, svg, mask, gsap

I want to animate (to over simplify, assume Scale+) a Text Mask in a SVG (It has to be a mask).
I'm using GSAP to achieve this.

My animation will just play fine with Edge and Chrome, but fails with Firefox.

```js
var tl = new gsap.timeline();
   tl.add(
    gsap.to("#masktext", 3, {scale: 3, "text-anchor": "middle", transformOrigin: "50% 50%"}),
    "0"
   );
```

```css
.svg-container {
 font-size: 13rem;
 font-weight:bold;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 max-height:700px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
}

#mysvg {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 overflow: visible;
 display: block;
}

#masktext {
 text-anchor: middle;
 transform-origin: center center;
 }

#maskrect {
 fill: white;
}

#myrect {
 fill: white;
 -webkit-mask: url(#mask);
 mask: url(#mask);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.2.4/gsap.min.js"></script>
<div class="svg-container">
  <svg id="mysvg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1920 700"  width="1920px" height="700px" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
   
   <defs>
    <mask id="mask" x="0" y="0" width="1920" height="700"  maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse"  maskContentUnits="userSpaceOnUse" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice">
     <rect id="maskrect" x="0" y="0" width="1920" height="700"/>
     <text id="masktext" x="50%" y="50%">Creative</text>

    </mask>
    
   </defs>
   <rect id="myrect" x="0" y="0" width="1920" height="700" style="fill:green;"/>
  </svg>
   </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/yumigo/qcrawe2g/

My guess would be that under Firefox, the scaled position of the text is wrong/off scope and ruins the animation. Been searching around with transform origin and different initial text positions with no luck.

Comment: Side note: as of [GSAP 3](https://greensock.com/3/) it's more proper to put the duration inside of the vars parameter, not as the second parameter to your tweens.

Comment: Thank you Zach for pinpointing this

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems:

1. Firefox has several bugs. It won't allow getBBox() on an element that's not in the visible DOM, and it won't allow it on elements in a <mask>. GSAP already works around the first issue by sensing this condition and moving the element temporarily into an  that's in the root, but your particular scenario depends on the sizing of the mask and you're using a relative position like x="50%", so it'll throw things off. I don't see any reasonable way for us to alter GSAP to work around the -specific bug in Firefox.
2. Another Firefox bug: it doesn't paint changes to the mask unless the masked element itself has some kind of change.
3. You had "new gsap.timeline()", but that's not a constructor. Don't use the "new" keyword.

Here's a fixed version that uses svgOrigin so that it's absolute and doesn't depend on relative origin stuff like "50% 50%":

https://jsfiddle.net/rxva8gnu/1/

```
// use svgOrigin so that it's absolute and you don't need to rely on relative stuff like "50% 50%"
gsap.to("#masktext", {scale: 3, duration:3, textAnchor: "middle", svgOrigin: "960 260"});
gsap.to("#myrect", {x:"+=0.001", duration: 3}); // to work around another Firefox bug that won't repaint with the newly-transformed mask unless the myrect also has a changed property.
```

Does that help?

Comment: Hoooo yes it does help !
Thank you so much !!
Cristal clear answer and awesome resolution. I whish I could upvote
Cheers!